# When to use environment variables vs. system properties?

Tags: java, environment-variables, system-properties

I wonder which of the following is a preferred approach?

We can set things up as `APP_HOME=/path/to/file` (`export` in `.profile` or something along those lines) and access it as `System.getenv("APP_HOME")`

Or, alternatively using properties as `-DAPP_HOME=/path/to/file` and access it as `System.getProperty("APP_HOME")`

Now .. either one will make the value available for the application stand point, but is either approach preferred? Why? When?

Comment: Why would one be preferred over the other? IMO env vars should be overridden by options specified via -D, but other than that, meh.

Comment: Well, we have 2 options to do the same thing right? Hence the question

Comment: Why not use both? Search system properties for the key, and if not there, search the environment. They are not really the same thing, since one requires the value to be set explicitly for the application and the other not.

Comment: Also, note that getEnv used to be deprecated. If you are using Java 1.3 or 1.4, you should be using only system properties.

Comment: Ok cool. Nathan, please `answer` so i can accept it.

Comment: System properties can be set only by the process doing the invocation. Environnemnt variables can be set by any parent process, e.g. the login shell making it more accessible for administrators.  If you have full control, it most likely doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java 1.3 or 1.4 (and 1.2, IIRC), you should be using system properties, since `System.getenv` was deprecated. It was reinstated in Java 1.5. The relevant bug report can be found [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4199068).

You can use both. Search system properties for the key, and if it's not there, search the environment. This gives you the best of both worlds.

These really aren't the same thing: One requires the value to be set explicitly, and the other not. Also, note that the environment is a convenient place to put some strings for interoperability.

Comment: With the caveat that it's `System.getenv`, not `getEnv`.

Comment: The method System.getenv() should not be used to access environment variables because not all platforms have support for environment variables. -- Reasoning given by CodePro code analysis tool

Comment: @AnujBalan The default system environment should not be relied upon for platform-independent behavior. However, artificial (platform-independent) environments can be created for subprocesses via ProcessBuilder, so a strict prohibition on its use is likely to result in false positives being reported by a tool such as CodePro

Answer (score 21):

The Javadoc for `System.getenv(String)` addresses this question directly, [saying](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#EnvironmentVSSystemProperties):

> *System
>    properties* and *environment variables* are both
>    conceptually mappings between names and values.  Both
>    mechanisms can be used to pass user-defined information to a
>    Java process.  Environment variables have a more global effect,
>    because they are visible to all descendants of the process
>    which defines them, not just the immediate Java subprocess.
>    They can have subtly different semantics, such as case
>    insensitivity, on different operating systems.  For these
>    reasons, environment variables are more likely to have
>    unintended side effects.  **It is best to use system properties
>    where possible.**  Environment variables should be used when a
>    global effect is desired, or when an external system interface
>    requires an environment variable (such as `PATH`).

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet at the moment, so I will add a couple of points as an answer.

I agree with the javadoc's saying "It is best to use system properties where possible.", also in my own words previous to seeing this page here that the Java system variables are encapsulated inside the JVM. They are not visible to other processes on the host, and thus less coupled with the host system.

In addition, there are multiple interfaces to set the global environment variables, and so it could be a bit tricky to track all the values being used over time.

Answer (score 0):

One important difference between using Environment Variables (envs) and System properties which should be considered is that the envs could not be changed at runtime/in the running process, BUT System properties could be. Refer to the Javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperties-java.util.Properties-