# Eclipse Environment Variable Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Mars, and am running an application with some VM arguments and have environment variables defined on the run configuration

`TOMCAT_HOME c:\tomcat`

I have the following in the Environment tab VM arguments:
`-Dcatalina.home=${TOMCAT_HOME}`

I get the following error:

`Reference to undefined variable TOMCAT_HOME`

How come I am specifying the variable in the run configuration but it is not working as a VM arg?

Edit:

Turns out that the answer is that you need to add a **Classpath Variable** from **Window->Preferences** menu.  That's confusing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026558/when-to-use-environment-variables-vs-system-properties

Comment: @mikeb you must specify the variable to run the app on _Run Configuration Window_ to do it, so go to Run as... and put this new variable on _arguments tabs_ see the link https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/6039/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Environment` tab does not seem to work. Here is the way I could get this work:

1. In the `Run Configurations`, on the `Arguments` tab, click on `Variables` in `VM Arguments` section.
   [image]
2. Click on `Edit Variables`
   [image]
3. Click on `New`, add `Name` and `Value` to the variable
4. You can find the new variable added in the list. You can double-click on the item to add it to your `VM Arguments` pane.
   [image]
5. I have used it as `-Dcatalina.home=${TOMCAT_HOME}` and I could access this value from `System.getProperty("catalina.home")`

Comment: how do you 'use' it as -Dcatalina.home=${TOMCAT_HOME}?